# Getting values from child nodes in an element

Tags: javascript, extract

What I want to do can be done in three steps:
1. Find a specific element
2. Find specific child nodes in that element
3. Extract the values from those particular child nodes
I know, it's simple, but I'm new to JavaScript. Let's consider the following code, with comments to help us out.

```
<!--We're going to look at the content of this "p" tag-->
<p id="demo">
<!--Here we have a textbox and a drop down list-->
<input type="text" value="A Value"/>
<select>
<option value="zero">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
</p>
<!--This is the button that finds the "p" element with an id of "demo", then looks at  its child nodes.-->
<input type="button" onclick="extractV()" value="Get Values"/>
<script>
function extractV() {
document.getElementById("demo").//This is the bit that I don't know.
}
</script>
```

There you go. I can't find the correct tag to find a specific node in that tag (or any for that matter) and then extract their values but I know there's a way. If you know it that would be great. Any help to aid my endeavors is always greatly appreciated. Even constructive criticism I don't mind. Thank you!

**P.S: Don't think that I come to Stack Overflow to ask dumb questions. I've consulted books and other people. This is my last resort. If you have a question about the question then please ask.**

Comment: *getElementById* returns an element (or `null`), so have a look at the MDN documentation of the [*Element interface*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element). It also implements the [*Node*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) and [*EventTarget*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) interfaces (e.g. start with the Node [*childNodes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.childNodes) property). It has links to specifications, but MDN will be of more help for now (but don't forget to check the specs when you've finished).

Comment: Beside checking the specifications you should also consider using an DOM-Inspector so that you maybe can find the solution on your own. For DOM-Manipulations this may not be needed but if you're using some third party stuff later on, it would come in handy if you know how to deal with such tools. It also makes sense to get an abstact layer between the actual DOM-Modification and your Code, but I'm not sure if this is still needed. As far as I remember some DOM-Manip differs from Browser to Browser so the abstract layer will encapsulate this. P.S.: There are libraries out there for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/Kzwt9/

```
<!--We're going to look at the content of this "p" tag-->
<p id="demo">
<!--Here we have a textbox and a drop down list-->
<input type="text" value="A Value"/>
<select>
<option value="zero">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
</p>
<!--This is the button that finds the "p" element with an id of "demo", then looks at  its child nodes.-->
<input id="extractv" type="button" value="Get Values"/>
<script>
function extractV() {
  els = document.getElementById("demo").childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) {
    console.log( els[i].value );
  }
}
document.getElementById("extractv").addEventListener('click',extractV, false);
</script>
```